# Is there a way to hot-deploy delta changes onto an Android device? [Say, like JRebel]

Tags: java, android, hotdeploy, jrebel

I am an Indie Game Developer, and I am currently building a game for the Android Platform, using NDK.

My problem is that, this game is now more than 20MB in size and is taking a lot of time to deploy and start up on my Android Device, which is becoming a pain and is slowing me down.

So, I wanted to know

> Is any way to hot deploy just the delta changes, that I make to my Android Project, instead of building and installing the whole thing to my Android Device again and again?
>
> Is it even possible? I am looking for some thing like JRebel tool, for the Java VM and Java Containers.

[Update: Any other thoughts on bringing down the build time, please?]

Thanks and Cheers!

[Note: Just wanted to mention that I will not be be able to use the emulator for faster builds, because my game uses OpenGL library heavily, which the emulator cannot handle.]

Comment: Will keep the question open for a little while, hoping for more suggestions... 

[@CommonsWare : I appreciate the effort to answer my question. Please don't mind!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, I wanted to know if there is any way to hot deploy just the delta changes, that I make to my Android Project, instead of building and installing the whole thing to my Android Device again and again?

Not for stuff you are packaging inside your APK.

> Just wanted to mention that I will not be be able to use the emulator for faster builds, because my game uses OpenGL library heavily, which the emulator cannot handle.

I would hope that the latest emulators (with hardware acceleration) and the x86 emulator images for 2.3.3 and 4.0.3 would run your game acceptably fast.

Comment: hum.. unfortunate..

And thanks for the tip about emulators. Do you know of any references as to how to manage to run a game on the emulator? I am experimenting with couple of game engines too!

Comment: @dostiharise: " Do you know of any references as to how to manage to run a game on the emulator?" -- um, well, not specifically. Here is more general information about the new emulator options: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html

Comment: Thanks for the update on the new capabilities of the emulator. I think, I will have to live with the build times! :-/

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Actually hotswaping delta changes on Android is possible. You should use some special tools to achieve this behavior. You can try the tool: [InstaRelaoder](http://www.instareloader.com/download/) use "inirwetrust" as the password

Comment: why downvotes? At the beginning I posted the name, and got downvoted, now I didn't posted concrete info and still downvotes. How to tell people about possibly great tool?!

Answer (score 2):

JRebel is available for Android, and supports NDK projects.

https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 2.0 has now an [Instant Run](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run) feature.

[image]

More info in this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2016/04/android-studio-2-0.html).